# How to programmatically create several new cells in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to programmatically create several cells in a Jupyter notebook.

With this function I can create one cell

```
def create_new_cell(contents):
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    shell = get_ipython()
    shell.set_next_input(contents, replace=False)
```

But if I try to call it several times, for instance, from a for loop, like so

```
for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    create_new_cell(x)
```

It will only create one cell with the last item in the list. I've tried to find if there's a "flush" function or something similar but did not succeed.

Does anyone know how to properly write several cells programmatically?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I dug a bit more in the code of the `shell.payload_manager` and found out that in the current implementation of the `set_next_input` it does not pass the `single` argument to the `shell.payload_manager.write_payload` function. That prevents the notebook from creating several cells, since they all have the same source (the `set_next_input` function, in this case).

That being said, the following function works. It's basically the code from `write_payload` function setting the `single` parameter to `False`.

```
def create_new_cell(contents):
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    shell = get_ipython()

    payload = dict(
        source='set_next_input',
        text=contents,
        replace=False,
    )
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single=False)
```

Hope this helps someone out there ;)

Comment: Please provide an example of putting some code into the new cell programmatically

Comment: @WestCoastProjects You can use the function like so: `create_new_cell('print(123)')`. Is that what you were asking for?
The `contents` argument can be any Python code as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to create Markdown text ?

Comment: @braunmagrin - is there anyway to execute it?

Comment: This is not doing anything. I run it in my jupyter notebook as `create_new_cell("print('Hello world!')")`.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Very, very creative, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
def add_cell(text,  type='code', direct='above'):
    text = text.replace('\n','\\n').replace("\"", "\\\"").replace("'", "\\'")

    display(Javascript('''
    var cell = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_{}("{}")
    cell.set_text("{}")
    '''.format(direct, type, text)));

for i in range(3):
    add_cell(f'# heading{i}', 'markdown')
    add_cell(f'code {i}')
```

codes above will add cells as follows：[image]

Comment: I get the error Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

Comment: I get empty output