# How to hide/expand code/markdown cells in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-lab

**Question:** Is there a way to hide/show a block of Markdown/Code/Output cells in Jupyter Lab ?

**Objective**: I would like to have like a button which shows a correction, with several different cells and plots.

**Solutions I've looked at**:

- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517194/how-to-hide-one-specific-cell-input-or-output-in-ipython-notebook) only hide or show one input cell
- [Dynamically add cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987129/how-to-programmatically-create-several-new-cells-in-a-jupyter-notebook) could be ok, but I have to add several ones and run it, which is not possible through this solution
- I could insert cells by writing directly in the file.ipynb, when I a button is pushed, but then I should reload the notebook and I don't know if it's possible

Thank you !