# How do I create multiple new cells programmatically in IPython?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to create several new cells below the current cell. I found someone trying to do the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987129/how-to-programmatically-create-several-new-cells-in-a-jupyter-notebook). However, this seems to be out of date.

When using `.set_next_input(..., replace=False)` you can only update the next cell one time it seems. I also tried messing with `shell.payload_manager.write_payload(..., single=False` as mentioned in the linked post but it still only updates once.

Basically what I am trying to do is the following:

```
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython

ip = get_ipython()

for i in range(10):
    ip.shell.set_next_input(i, replace=False)
```

I am using version `'7.27.0'` of IPython.