# How to use `get_ipython().payload_manager.write_payload` create markdown cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I want to programmatically create several markdown cells in a Jupyter notebook.

the following function works for code cells, but not markdown cells.

```
def create_new_cell(contents):
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    shell = get_ipython()

    payload = {
        "source": "set_next_input",
        "text": contents,
        "replace": False
    }
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single=False)
```

I try to add metadata setting, but it doesn't work.

```
def create_new_cell(contents):
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    shell = get_ipython()

    payload = {
        "source": "set_next_input",
        "text": contents,
        "metadata": {"cell_type": "markdown"},
        "replace": False
    }
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single=False)
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Please cite/ link the source of your first code block. (Maybe from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987401/8508004)?) Thanks.

Comment: Given [this exchange 'How to programmatically create a markdown cell?'](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-programmatically-create-a-markdown-cell/14062/4?u=fomightez) I don't think it is possible directly running it in the notebook itself. ipylab may be a way (?), see under 'Execute Commands' [here](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#execute-commands), but I haven't found the magic combination yet.